# How do I rewrite in apache by converting a url to a 16digit hex?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I have the url `/a/b/main/ID/name.ext`; I'd like to grab the ID and convert it to an 8 byte hex value (16 digits). Then I would like to grab the file (assuming the id is 112233445566FF)

```
/main/00/11/22/33/44/55/66/FF/name.ext
```

In apache how do I convert the ID to 16 digit hex number and rewrite the url?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the easiest solution is to make a small script responsible for paths matching `/a/b/main/ID/name.ext`, and have it issue a redirect to the appropriate path.

Comment: How would i do that? also, the solution should work with binary files that can be resumed and audio files that can seek (say a 6mb demo m4a)

Comment: i still have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You would need a script, that would take the original URL, split it into components, and rewrite it with the ID expanded.  This should be easy in Python, Ruby, Perl, etc., and possible with /bin/sh (but I don't have recommend that).  You would place this in your server's cgi-bin directory, then use a RewriteRule to redirect access to `/a/b/main/ID/name.ext` to your script.  Your script would then issue a `302` response with a `Location:` header to redirect the client to the appropriate location.